# Flex: XMLList of attirubites.... convert to nodes?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3, e4x

say I have an xmllist like this (but with many other attributes not shown for brevity):

```
<node metal="white gold"/>
<node metal="yellow gold"/>
<node metal="silver"/>
```

and I access the metal attributes via xmllist.@metal which will give me a new xmllist like this:

```
white gold
yellow gold
silver
```

I want to convert that to an xmllist that looks like this:

```
<item label="White Gold" data="white gold"/>
<item label="Yellow Gold" data="yellow gold"/>
<item label="Silver" data="silver"/>
```

This way I can use it as a dataProvider in a combobox.

Anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the labelField of the ComboBox as "@metal". Better yet, have a custom labelFunction that changes the values in @label to title casing as required in your example.